# How to check why a MySQL stored function returns an empty result?

Tags: php, mysql

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `monthtargetbyuser`(`userId` BIGINT,month VARCHAR(11),year VARCHAR(11)) RETURNS int(11)

BEGIN 

  DECLARE target,da BIGINT;
  set da = year-month;

  SET target = (SELECT ifnull(user_target.monthly_target,0) as monthly_target from user_target left join users on users.id=user_target.user_id where date_format(users.doj,'%Y-%m') <= 'da' and user_target.year=year and year(users.doj)>0 and users.locked !=1 and users.id =userId );  


  RETURN target;
END
```

While executing the MySQL query given in the function, it returns an empty result or zero rows. But while executing the stored function, it gives incorrect result, i.e, it returns a value. How do I check that the MySQL function returns an empty result?

Answer (score 0):

Some smart person will probably give a better answer but what worked for me was to add a check at the end of the function, to see if the variable was null and if it was then set it to a value such as Unknown. That way you always get a value returned from the function, even when no rows are returned from your query, eg:

```
  SET target = (SELECT ifnull(user_target.monthly_target,0) as monthly_target from user_target left join users on users.id=user_target.user_id where date_format(users.doj,'%Y-%m') <= 'da' and user_target.year=year and year(users.doj)>0 and users.locked !=1 and users.id =userId );  

  IF (target IS NULL) THEN
        SET target = "Unknown";
  END IF;

  RETURN target;
```